# How to change color of QtCreator block highlighting?

Tags: qt, colors, qt-creator, syntax-highlighting, highlight

https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-highlighting.html
is interesting but the color scheme on macOS don't feel perfect. How to change color of QtCreator block highlighting?

I mean the Options > Text Editor > Display > Highlight blocks

A block will be i.e. the scope of a function.

Comment: I deleted my answer, based on the original text, I misunderstood what you meant by "block".